# React Event handler failed to triggered in onScroll events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mouseevent, onscrolllistener

I am trying to listen to a scroll event.
Here is the original code I converted.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
const headerChange = document.querySelector("header");
if (window.scrollY > 0) {
headerChange.classList.add("scrolled");
} 
else {
headerChange.classList.remove("scrolled");
} 
})
```

while this is the way i converted it in my react code..

```
const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
    const navRef = useRef();


    const navScroll = () => {

        setIsScrolling(window.scrollY > 0 ? 
        navRef.current.classList.add("scrolled") 
        :  navRef.current.classList.remove("scrolled"));
        console.log(navScroll)
    }

return (
<nav
    ref={navRef} 
    onScroll={() => isScrolling}>

</nav>

)
```

the scroll event failed to triggered when the page was scrolled

Please, what could be the reason while the scroll function failed to triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to the page scroll, and not the `nav` scrolling, so you still need to use `document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);`. Listening for DOM events is a side effect, that should be handled by `useEffect`. When the event is fired, you should update the state, and the state change should change the `className` - `className={isScrolling ? 'scrolled' : ''`.

```
const Header = () => {
  const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => setIsScrolling(window.scrollY > 0);
    
    document.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    
    return () => { // cleanup
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav className={isScrolling ? 'scrolled' : ''}>
    ...
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. one more thing. 

how about if I try to apply the same in forEach.

for example,

**document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav");
  for (const l of links) l.classList.toggle('scrolling', window.scrollY > 0);
})**


sorry to stress you a bit
Thanks once again.

Comment: You don't update class manually via DOM methods in React, because the next render might reset all changes. Pass the `isScrolling`  state via props to all child components and `nav` and let each of them react to it.

Comment: fully understood now,

many thanks